# jQuery Drag&Drop "Windows Like" Multi Select Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess you all know the Windows Style of selecting multible Objects (for example on your Desktop view) by drawing that dotted box and all elements with in will be marked. If you darg'n'drop one of those marked elements, all of them will move.

In fact I am searching for a jQuery plugin implementing that drag'n'drop multi select feature on web based views (DOM).

Any recommendations?

Yours agenty

Comment: google search for `jquery drag select` lists a few options, i think [this one](https://github.com/pykiss/jQuery.dragToSelect) is what you want

Comment: Thx, that plugin did it for me